# HTML DOM get length of font style in a paragraph which has ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is what I've done

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.links.length;
var y = document.images.length;
alert("Links = " + x + " , " + "Images = " + y);
}
```

Trying to get the length of different things in my site....

So far I've found how to get the length of the links and the images but I can't find ANY answer regarding font Styles...

I've found only this one

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontStyle = "italic";
```

in W3schools but is used only to change text into italic not getting the length of italics in a paragraph like I want for the last half hour....

for example

```
<p id="italic"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<em>Donec at erat semper,</em> tempor magna sed, aliquet lorem.
Morbi iaculis libero sed <em>elementum</em> fermentum. <p>
```

of course there are more paragraphs with different IDs

Comment: What result do you want? The number of elements that are italicised, or the number of `<em>` elements? Or the number of characters? Please show the precise result you expect, and explain *why* that is the result you want, because - as written - your expectation isn't entirely clear.

Comment: I thought that was the same actually... the italics are inside the em right? so... the italics inside are the em. i suppose that's right. cause I haven't seen it in action to know for sure :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to find is the number of `<em>` elements in the document as a whole:

```
var italicisedElements = document.getElementsByTagName('em').length;
```

```js
var italicisedElements = document.getElementsByTagName('em').length;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Number of &lt;em&gt; elements: ' + italicisedElements;
```

```html
<p id="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <em>Donec at erat semper,</em> tempor magna sed, aliquet lorem. Morbi iaculis libero sed <em>elementum</em> fermentum.
</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

To find the number of `<em>` elements within an element of a given `id`, such as `id="italic"`:

```
var italicisedElements = document.querySelectorAll('#italic em').length;
```

```js
var italicisedElements = document.querySelectorAll('#italic em').length;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Number of &lt;em&gt; elements: ' + italicisedElements;
```

```html
<p id="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <em>Donec at erat semper,</em> tempor magna sed, aliquet lorem. Morbi iaculis libero sed <em>elementum</em> fermentum.
</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

To find all elements in the `document` whose CSS (whether in-line, with the `style` attribute, or set via CSS elsewhere) styles the text as `italic`:

```
var all = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('*') ),
    italicisedElements = all.filter(function(node){
      return window.getComputedStyle(node).fontStyle === 'italic';
    }).length;

console.log(italicisedElements);
```

```js
var all = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')),
  italicisedElements = all.filter(function(node) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(node).fontStyle === 'italic';
  }).length;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Number of &lt;em&gt; elements: ' + italicisedElements;
```

```html
<p id="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <em>Donec at erat semper,</em> tempor magna sed, aliquet lorem. Morbi iaculis libero sed <em>elementum</em> fermentum.
</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That's actually it :D Thx a lot :D

Comment: No problem, I'm just glad to have helped; thank you for the acceptance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the pure javascript answer:

```js
function func(parent_css_selector, child_css_selector)
{
  return document.querySelectorAll(parent_css_selector + ">" + child_css_selector).length;
}

console.log("we have " + func('body', 'img') + " 'img' elements in 'body'");
console.log("we have " + func('body', 'a') + " 'a' elements in 'body'");
console.log("we have " + func('#italic', 'em') + " 'em' elements in '#italic'");
```

```html
<img src='1.jpg' />
<img src='2.jpg' />
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<p id="italic"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<em>Donec at erat semper,</em> tempor magna sed, aliquet lorem.
Morbi iaculis libero sed <em>elementum</em> fermentum. </p>
```

you can use JQuery for a simplest way.

Comment: OOh cool one too... This is definitely a nice bookmark for later use :D gonna try this too :D Thx a alot :D

Comment: @GreekGreekGG :if this is your requested answer, you can select this ;)